# Audio language identification

Tags: audio, cmusphinx

I'm looking for an open source library to detect the spoken language used in an audio file, such as a wav file.

I tried CMU sphinx , but was not able to understand how to use it for language detection? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to learn another toolkit, you should consider Kaldi [[1](http://kaldi.sourceforge.net/about.html)]. It is an open-source speech recognition toolkit with a speaker recognition system (which uses similar models as a language identification system) in the trunk and an experimental language Identification setup in the sandbox language_id. After checking out the repository, you can switch to the LID sandbox with svn switch ^/sandbox/language_id. The LID examples are in egs/lre07.

Whichever toolkit you use, I recommend an i-Vector based system instead of a phonotactic system. An i-Vector based system will be easier to setup as it doesn't require transcripts, and significantly faster, since it avoids decoding.

Answer (score 1):

You can try CMU sphinx in all phone decode mode.
Train models for languages you wish to identify.
Pick language for which hypothesis score is best